# Multiple Data Structures in C

Tags: c, object, queue

I have a file queue.c that defines a Queue in C. How would I make 3 separate queues independent of each other? I'm not very experienced with C, and I keep thinking of it in an OO view, and I know that I can't do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
} *Head, *Tail;

void addCharacter(char c)
{
    struct Node *temp1, *temp2;
    temp1 = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp1->data = c;

    temp2 = Tail;

    if(Head == NULL)
    {
        Head = temp1;
        Head->next = NULL;
        Tail = Head;
    }
    else
    {
        Tail = temp1;
        temp1->next = NULL;
        temp2->next = temp1;
    }
}

void deleteCharacter()
{
    struct Node *temp1 = Head;
    Head = temp1->next;
    free(temp1);
}

int replaceCharacter(char c)
{
    Head->data = c;
}

int main() {}
```

That's my Queue, and all I have for another C file is essentially:

```
#include "queue.h"
```

I don't know where to go from there...

Comment: OO is a design style, not a language feature.  There's nothing wrong in using it to program in C.  Define your objects as structs, pass a pointers to them to each 'method' (there's no implicit 'self', so you have to do it explicitly) and you're almost there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of making `Head` and `Tail` global variables, make another struct that contains them, e.g.:

```
struct Queue {
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
};
```

Then change your functions operating on a queue to take a pointer to a `Queue` struct, and operate on that.

You will also want a `initQueue` function that initializes `head` and `tail` to `NULL`. Then using a queue can look like:

```
struct Queue queue1;
initQueue(&queue1);
addCharacter(&queue1, 'a');
//....
```

Comment: Oh well, that makes more sense to me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could just define a new structure for queue.

```
struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
};
struct Queue
{
    struct Node *Head, *Tail;
    // optional int size;
};
```

And then for each function add another parameter:

```
void addCharacter(struct Queue *q, char c);

void deleteCharacter(struct Queue *q);
```

And access with `q->Head` and `q->Tail`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you design this queue library? In its current form you cannot have more than one queue because the function use the global pointers `Head` and `Tail` and there no way to tell your functions to use some other pointers.

Comment: I'm curious why this was thumbed down.

Answer (score 0):

You have a global `Head` and `Tail`.  If you want multiple lists, you need multiple heads.  So you will need to change your functions so that `&Head` and `&Tail` are parameters.